# Trigger Excel Worksheet_Change to change cells using R

Tags: r, excel, vba

I modify a cell in an Excel file using R.

When this cell is manually changed, Worksheet_Change launches to indicate the date of the modification (in two other cells).

When I run my code in R, the date of the modification in column 46 (see VBA code ModificationDate1) is indicated. The date of the modification in column 40 (see VBA code ModificationDate2) doesn't appear. I get a VBA error 1004.

It is not indicated where the error appears. I can't click debug.

I would like the date of the modification in column 40 to also appear. (This later appears when I make a change directly in Excel.)

**My code in R:**

```r
if (NewInput != CurrentData) {
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  wb <- xlApp[["Workbooks"]]$Open("path.xlsm")
  sheet <- wb$Worksheets("Sheet1")
  cell  <- sheet$Cells(Outputrow + 6, 7)
  cell[["Value"]] <- paste0(NewInput)
  wb$Save()
  xlApp$Quit()
  }
```

**My codes in vba:**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'**ModificationDate1**
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range(Cells(7, 7), Cells(LastRow, 7))

If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
    Call UnprotectCells
    Cells(Target.Row, 46).Value = Date
    Call ProtectCells
End If

'**ModificationDate2**
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Range(Cells(7, 3), Cells(LastRow, 4))
Set rng2 = Range(Cells(7, 7), Cells(LastRow, 10))

If Not Intersect(Target, Union(rng1, rng2)) Is Nothing Then
    Call UnprotectCells
    Cells(Target.Row, 40).Value = Date
    Call ProtectCells
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the RTE 1004?

Comment: That's the issue. It is not indicated where the error appears. But the vba code runs well when I make the change myself without R.

Comment: What line is highlighted when you click `Debug` after the error message appears?

Comment: I can't click debug. :(